# OR operator not working for Breeze Query using Json

Tags: sql, json, breeze

I am using Breeze api to write client side queries and want to use Json for the same.

I have a SQL query which I converted to Json query, but it is converting 'or' operator to 'and' automatically. Please help.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [Users] WHERE [Id] IN (1,3) AND [Name] = 'abc' OR [Mobile] = '111'
```

**BREEZE JSON QUERY**

```
var jsonQuery = {
  "from": 'User',
  "where": [{
     "and": [{
        "Id": { "in": [1, 3] },
        "Name": { "eq": 'abc' }
     }],
     "or": [{
        "Mobile": { "eq": '111' }
     }]
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm editing this in the SO editor so I haven't performed any syntax checking on it but you should be able to get the idea

```
var jsonQuery = {
  "from": 'User',
  "where": [{
    "or": [ {
      "and": [ {
        "Id": { "in": [1, 3] },
        "Name": { "eq": 'abc' }
      }],
      "Mobile": { "eq": '111' }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Jay, but I tried your query and here also OR operator is translated to AND. The only place where I can find OR operators are in IN operator.

Comment: Just if it could help. Below are the details of breeze.debug.js file which I am using    --  "version": "1.5.4" & "metadataVersion": "1.0.5"

Answer (score 1):

Jay's solution was correct, but as he pointed out it was syntax issue. The correct query is:

```
var jsonQuery = {
  "from": 'User',
  "where": [{
    "or": [
      { "and": [
          { "Id": { "in": [1, 3] }},
          { "Name": { "eq": 'abc' }}
        ]
      },
      { "Mobile": { "eq": '111' }}
    }]
  }]
}
```